# how to import "changing name" file in python?

Tags: python

I am using

```
from file import *
```

commands. The file I want to import (within my directory) changes its name, that's why I want to do it like this:

```
fileName="variable"
from fileName import *
```

But this doesn't work of course.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Best

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking. Can you edit your question and add a bit more detail?

Comment: Also, what version of Python? And take a look at the questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dynamic+import+file+%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aquestion+hasaccepted%3Ayes). I would guess you are duplicating at least a few of those.

Comment: Is it `file` that changes or what exactly?

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity, what's your use case?  I'm trying to think of a situation in which I'd want to do this, but can't.  Doesn't mean there isn't one, just means I'm insufficiently imaginative.  Is it always the "same" file, and the name of the file is changing, or are you importing a different module in different situaions?

Answer (score 4):

This is done using [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module). For example, importing 'hello.py':

```
import importlib
h = importlib.import_module('hello')
```

This is equivalent to:

```
import hello as h
```

Comment: It would be better to use `importlib.import_module`, rather than calling `__import__` directly.

Comment: I assume the OP has some method of determining the name of the file to import. For example, the filename might partially change but have a constant part, facilitating selection from a list of files in the current directory.